# Derive the commutation relation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm having difficulty in deriving the commutation relation:

[E<sub>ij</sub>, E<sub>kl</sub>] = $\delta$<sub>jk</sub> E<sub>il</sub> - $\delta$<sub>il</sub> E<sub>kj</sub>

Here E<sub>ij</sub> is a matrix with null entries everywhere at the i'th row and j'th column, where it is 1.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please say what you mean by $[.,.]$? And what are $E_{i,j}$ and $E_{k,l}$? Btw. $\delta$ works :-)

Comment: Note the difference between $/delta$ and $\delta$, where the last one is done by $\backslash delta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the notation correctly, $E_{ij}$ is a matrix with entries zero except the $ij$ entry which is one. Therefore, the $ab$ component of the product of two such matrices is 
$$(E_{ij}E_{kl})_{ab}=\sum_t (E_{ij})_{at}(E_{kl})_{tb}=\sum_t \delta_{ia}\delta_{jt}\delta_{kt}\delta_{lb}=\delta_{ia}\delta_{jk}\delta_{lb}=\delta_{jk}(E_{il})_{ab}$$

and likewise for the commuted product, leading to the commutator by making the difference.